# Como manter uma caixa de seleção true depois que uma mensagem de erro é exibida?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Como posso manter uma caixa de seleção **true** quando eu exibir mensagem de erro? Toda vez que eu exibir um `errorMessage` minha checkBox transforma em **false**. Como posso resolver esse problema? Eu estou usando `jsf2.0` e `primefaces`.

Este é o botão que chama um método:

```
    <p:commandButton styleClass="btIcon" 
                                 value="Consolidar"
                                 image="addIcon"
                                 process="@this :formCadastro"
                                 actionListener="#{bean.addConsolidacao}"
                                 onclick="carregando.show();"
                                 oncomplete="carregando.hide();" 
                                 rendered="true" 
                                 update="@this :formCadastro :formPanel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu percebi o problema, quando a página é rerenderizada a caixa de seleção não faz parte da entidade. A solução é apenas definir um transiente na entidade, a fim de manipulá-lo.

```
    @Transient
private Boolean acaoCheck;

public Boolean getAcaoCheck() {
    return acaoCheck;
}

public void setAcaoCheck(Boolean acaoCheck) {
    this.acaoCheck = acaoCheck;
}
```